# Android: Add button at very end of the gridview

Tags: android, gridview, footer

I have a grid view which shows some items. The user can scroll down and up. I want to be able to show a button at the very end of the grid view when the user has scrolled to the end. This button will not show when the user is not at the bottom of the grid. How can this be done ?

When the user is not at the end, the grid should look like this
[image]

and upon reaching the end of the gridview, a button should be added as a footer to gridview.

[image]

Comment: Can you add more information? May be some images? Because it's so hard to perception.

Comment: @Vihaan excuse me if i don't understand but isn't this normal behaviour of scrolling the view to hide or not to hide the button? Perhaps you mean mood when view is not so long to be scrolled?

Comment: @DomenicoPacecca :Consider the gridview has 20 items, out of which only 10 are visible. When the user scrolls down and reaches the end i.d on the 20th view, that is the time when the button appears.

Answer (score 2):

Gridview doesn't allow you to add a footer view but you can program it.

take a look at this [answer from Frank](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20489671/1182971).

He has added a scrolllistner and only shows the button when you are getting close to the end.